# How to extract speed from gpx with "track points badly ordered"

Tags: gpsbabel

I'm trying to convert gpx (without speed information) to csv (with speed information). I have `gpx` file that contains multiple `<trk>` tags, each one contains one `trkseg` with track points. All track points seem to be correctly ordered (from quick scrolling trough it). (Data are recorded by human, so there are segments probably because human paused recording.)

I have used following command from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/202456/109604) answer:

```
gpsbabel -t -i gpx -f input.gpx -x track,speed -o unicsv -F output.csv
```

I got following error:

```
trackfilter-init: Track points badly ordered (timestamp 2008-10-09T16:16:06Z > 2008-10-09T16:15:55Z)!
```

Is there a way to automatically fix this? I don't necessarily need to process file as multiple segments, I need to dump everything to one `csv`.

Answer (score 2):

I used `merge` filter to merge multiple tracks:

```
gpsbabel -t -i gpx -f input.gpx -x track,merge,speed -o unicsv -F output.csv
```